# How to sum by month in timestamp Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like this :

| trx_date | trx_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-02-11 | 35 |
| 2014-03-10 | 26 |
| 2011-02-9 | 10 |
| 2013-02-12 | 5 |
| 2013-01-11 | 21 |

how do i filter that into month and year? so that i can sum the trx_amount

example expected output :

| trx_monthly | trx_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-02 | 40 |
| 2013-01 | 21 |
| 2014-02 | 35 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert values to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df['trx_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trx_date'])

df1 = (df.groupby(df['trx_date'].dt.to_period('m').rename('trx_monthly'))['trx_amount']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='trx_sum'))
print (df1)
  trx_monthly  trx_sum
0     2011-02       10
1     2013-01       21
2     2013-02       40
3     2014-03       26
```

Or convert datetimes to strings in format `YYYY-MM` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby(df['trx_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').rename('trx_monthly'))['trx_amount']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='trx_sum'))
print (df2)
  trx_monthly  trx_sum
0     2011-02       10
1     2013-01       21
2     2013-02       40
3     2014-03       26
```

---

Or convert to month and years, then output is different - 3 columns:

```
df2 = (df.groupby([df['trx_date'].dt.year.rename('year'), 
                  df['trx_date'].dt.month.rename('month')])['trx_amount']
         .sum()
         .reset_index(name='trx_sum'))
print (df2)
   year  month  trx_sum
0  2011      2       10
1  2013      1       21
2  2013      2       40
3  2014      3       26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
df['trx_month'] = df['trx_date'].dt.month

df_agg = df.groupby('trx_month')['trx_sum'].sum()
```